# Generate random correlated variable from known $X$

Tags: regression, random-generation, excel

I want to use Excel to generate a random correlated $Y$ from a known $X$.  From another thread, I found the equation $Y = r\cdot X + E$, where $X$ is standardized and $E$ is a random variable from normal distribution having mean $0$ and $\sigma = \sqrt{(1-r^2)}$.  I assume $r$ is the correlation coefficient found using Excel's `CORREL` function.  I also assume I can calculate $E$ by using Excel's `NORMDIST` function.

Are my assumptions correct? If I have a known $X$, how do I "standardize" $X$?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: $r$ is the correlation that you _want_ $X$ and $Y$ to have, not something computed via Excel. A standardized $X$, call it $\hat{X}$, is related to $X$ via $$\hat{X} = \frac{X - \mu}{\sigma}$$ where $\mu$ is the mean value of $X$ viz.,the average of the $N$ cells if $X$ is stored in an array of $N$ cells, and $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of the $N$ values of $X$. $\hat{X}$ has mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$. Your equation thus is $$Y = r * \hat{X} + E,$$ and $Y$ is also a standardized random variable with mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$. $aY+b$ also has correlation $r$ with $X$.

Comment: So is this the equation?

(Y-meanY)/sdY = r * (X-meanX)/sdX + E

where E is a random variable from a normal distribution with mean 0 and sd sqrt(1-r^2)?  Still confused as to what r is in my example.

Comment: Yes, your equation is correct. As to $r$, you need to look at the specifications _given_ to you when you were told "Create a random variable $Y$ that is correlated with $X$". The statement _should_ have included a specification of $r$ e.g. "... that has correlation $r = 0.8$ with $X$". If your client/professor/boss/colleague did not say what value of $r$ is desired, ask! $r$ should be between $-1$ and $+1$. All else failing, set $r=\sqrt{1-r^2}=1/\sqrt{2} \approx 0.7071$ because _I_ said to do so. Hey, if you can't trust something you read on the Internet, what's the world coming to?

Comment: Thanks.  I think I am close now.  Here is the equation I am using:  Y = (((r*((actualX-meanX)/stdX))+RN)*stdY)+meanY, where RN = a random normal variable with mean 0 and std of sqrt(1-r^2).  However, I am still confused about r.  This is not an assignment so no one is giving me a target correlation.  My goal remains to generate the most accurate possible random Y from a known X using what I have found from regression analysis.  When using the above formula, the generated Ys are highly affected by r so it seems to be important to use a proper r.

Comment: From which thread did you find that formula? I would like to have a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If $X \sim N(0, 1)$ and $Y = rX + \epsilon$,
where $\epsilon \sim N(0, 1 - r^2)$, 
then $Cor(X, Y) = r$.

By definition,
\begin{align*}
    Cor(X, Y) 
    &= \frac{E((X - E(X))(Y - E(Y)))}{\sqrt{Var(X)Var(Y)}} \\
    &= \frac{E(XY)}{\sqrt{Var(Y)}} \\
    &= \frac{E(rX^2 + \epsilon X)}{\sqrt{Var(rX + \epsilon)}}
\end{align*}

Assuming $X$ and $\epsilon$ are independent, we have

\begin{align*}
    Cor(X, Y) 
    &= \frac{rE(X^2) + E(\epsilon)E(X)}{\sqrt{Var(rX) + Var(\epsilon)}} \\
    &= \frac{rE(X^2)}{\sqrt{r^2 + 1 - r^2}} \\
    &= rE(X^2) \\
\end{align*}

Since $X^2 \sim \chi^2(1)$, we get $Cor(X, Y) = r$.

This can also be verified by a simple simulation in R:

```
require(foreach)
x = matrix(rnorm(1000*1000), 1000)
err = matrix(rnorm(1000*1000, 0, sqrt(1  - .1^2)), 1000)
myd = (.1*x + err)
allr = foreach(i=1:1000, .combine='c') %do% cor(x[, i], myd[, i])
png('a.png')
hist(allr)
dev.off()
```

[image]